# Searching a word in a given string array

Tags: java, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

> You are given a 2D array as a string and a word via keyboard. The word
>   can be in any way (all 8 neighbors to be considered) but you can’t use
>   same character twice while matching. Return word's first and last
>   character's index as (x,y). If match is not found return -1.

That's the question. I'm having trouble with searching. I tried that:

```
int x=0,y=0;
            for(int f=0; f<WordinArray.length; f++){
                for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].length; j++){
                        if(matrix[i][j].equals(WordinArray[f])){
                            x=i; y=j;
                            System.out.print("("+x+","+y+")");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But, That code is not working as it is supposed to. How else I can write this searching code?

Comment: `(all 8 neighbors to be considered` : explain about it a little more

Comment: Eight possible directions: horizontally, vertically, and diagonally  
XY( 0, 1 ), XY( 0, -1 ), XY( 1, 0 ), XY( -1, 0 )  
XY( 1, 1 ), XY( 1, -1 ), XY( -1, 1 ), XY( -1, -1 )

Comment: Are you saying this is an array of letters, like a word-search puzzle?

Comment: Is this your problem? http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=31&page=show_problem&problem=951

Comment: Word is taken as a String. It doesn't have to be in a Array. But, I thought that It could be better, If I searched the word as array in the 2D array.

Comment: @ExceptionalException No, It is not. But, I guess, It is very similar.

Comment: I can give you some hints in how to do it (I have done this code). 1 - You will need a recursion, 2 - You will need a recursion, and finally you will need a recursion.

Comment: Exactly, I need a recursion. But the problem is that, I have not known how to do recursion yet. Therefore, I have to write that code without recursion. @JorgeCampos

Comment: @Sixie Check my answer, and accept it if it's correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [Sixie's code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y1OW1RYxcchn6tx3ou4qqdjEIB_qjK0JIEou29oJ8pg/edit?pli=1)

Assuming this is a valid input/output to your program?

```
Size:
4x4
Matrix:
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
Word: afkp
(0,0)(3,3)
```

I edited your code, so that it should work for input on this form (it is case sensitive at the moment, but can easily be changed by setting `.toLowerCase()`

```
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Size: ");
String s = k.nextLine();
s.toUpperCase();

int Xindex = s.indexOf('x');
int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, Xindex));
int y = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(Xindex + 1));

System.out.println("Matrix:");
char[][] matrix = new char[x][y];

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int p = 0; p < y; p++) {
        matrix[i][p] = k.next().charAt(0);
    }
}

System.out.print("Word: ");
String word = k.next();

int xStart = -1, yStart = -1;
int xEnd = -1, yEnd = -1;

// looping through the matrix
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        // when a match is found at the first character of the word
        if (matrix[i][j] == word.charAt(0)) {
            int tempxStart = i;
            int tempyStart = j;
            // calculating all the 8 normals in the x and y direction
            // (the 8 different directions from each cell)
            for (int normalX = -1; normalX <= 1; normalX++) {
                for (int normalY = -1; normalY <= 1; normalY++) {
                    // go in the given direction for the whole length of
                    // the word
                    for (int wordPosition = 0; wordPosition < word
                            .length(); wordPosition++) {
                        // calculate the new (x,y)-position in the
                        // matrix
                        int xPosition = i + normalX * wordPosition;
                        int yPosition = j + normalY * wordPosition;
                        // if the (x,y)-pos is inside the matrix and the
                        // (x,y)-vector normal is not (0,0) since we
                        // dont want to check the same cell over again
                        if (xPosition >= 0 && xPosition < x
                                && yPosition >= 0 && yPosition < y
                                && (normalX != 0 || normalY != 0)) {
                            // if the character in the word is not equal
                            // to the (x,y)-cell break out of the loop
                            if (matrix[xPosition][yPosition] != word
                                    .charAt(wordPosition))
                                break;
                            // if the last character in the word is
                            // equivalent to the (x,y)-cell we have
                            // found a full word-match.
                            else if (matrix[xPosition][yPosition] == word
                                    .charAt(wordPosition)
                                    && wordPosition == word.length() - 1) {
                                xStart = tempxStart;
                                yStart = tempyStart;
                                xEnd = xPosition;
                                yEnd = yPosition;
                            }
                        } else
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("(" + xStart + "," + yStart + ")(" + xEnd + ","
        + yEnd + ")");
k.close();
```

Comment: Program works as you wrote at first. I wrote `blocksAvailable[][]` to understand If that location has been controlled. Also `reversedWord` is for searching word's reverse. I mean, the program must search and find either ROAD and DAOR's first and last indexes. In addition, program must find words which might be given transverse,horizontal and vertical.

Comment: @Sixie Added solution

Comment: Thank you for your help! Apparently, I was trying hard way. I didn't even think of taking matrix as char.

Comment: @Sixie No problem. Please approve the answer so that other people with similar problem can use this code example too!

Comment: You might want to consider using clearer variable names than `i`, `j`, `k`, `k1`, `x`, `y`, `xx`, `yy`, `x1` and `y1`.  It's impossible to know what variable does what, which makes this code kind of unmaintainable.  By answering a question like this, you're teaching someone how to program; and this is not a good style to teach.

Comment: @DavidWallace I simply took his code (which is in the link in the top of the answer) and adjusted it. I can rewrite it with more sensible variables at a later time. I totally agree. Although `i`, `j`, `x`, `y` are generally used to traverse a 2D-array, but the rest I can make clearer.

Comment: I don't see `xx`, `yy`, `x1` and `y1` in Sixie's code.  I really think that if you're going to try to teach someone how to do something, it's a mistake to propagate bad programming habits.

Comment: @DavidWallace Edited it now. Sorry I rushed it at first. I don't really have time for this at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to plan your algorithm a bit more carefully before you start writing code.  If I were doing it, my algorithm might look something like this.

(1) Iterate through the array, looking for the first character of the word.

(2) Each time I find the first character, check out all 8 neighbours, to see if any is the second character.

(3) Each time I find the second character as a neighbour of the first, iterate along the characters in the array, moving in the correct direction, and checking each character against the word.

(4) If I have matched the entire word, then print out the place where I found the match and stop.

(5) If I have reached the edge of the grid, or found a character that doesn't match, then continue with the next iteration of loop (2).

Once you have your algorithm nailed down, think about how to convert each step to code.

Comment: I worked on algorithm as you suggested. But this time the problem has changed. I couldn't be able to print first and last letter's indexes.

Comment: OK, if you'd like to paste your new code into the question, I will take a look and see if I can work out what your problem is.  Don't replace the old code (because that would change the question); just append the new code to the end.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question right. This is a quick answer I made now.

```
int H = matrix.length;
int W = matrix[0].length;
int xStart = -1, yStart = -1;
int xEnd = -1, yEnd = -1;

String word = "WordLookingFor".toLowerCase();

for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == word.charAt(0)) {
            int tempxStart = i;
            int tempyStart = j;
            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) {
                        int xx = i+x*k;
                        int yy = j+y*k;
                        if(xx >= 0 && xx < H && yy >= 0 && yy < W && (x != 0 || y != 0)) {
                            if(matrix[xx][yy] != word.charAt(k))
                                break;
                            else if (matrix[xx][yy] == word.charAt(k) && k == word.length()-1) {
                                xStart = tempxStart;
                                yStart = tempyStart;
                                xEnd = xx;
                                yEnd = yy;
                            }
                        } else
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A little trick I used for checking all the 8 neighbors is to use two for-loops to create all the directions to go in:

```
for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
        if(x !=0 || y != 0)
            System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
    }
}
```

This creates

```
-1, -1
-1, 0
-1, 1
0, -1
0, 1
1, -1
1, 0
1, 1
```

Notice: All but 0,0 (you don't want to revisit the same cell).
The rest of the code is simply traversing though the matrix of characters, and though the whole length of the word you are looking for until you find (or maybe you don't find) a full match.

Answer (score 0):

> This time the problem is that how could I print word's first and last
>   letter's indexes. I tried various ways like printing after each word
>   was searched. But, all of them didn't work. I am about to blow up.

```
int[] values = new int[2];
                for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].length; j++){

                        if(Character.toString(word.charAt(0)).equals(matrix[i][j]) == true || Character.toString(ReversedWord.charAt(0)).equals(matrix[i][j]) == true ){
                            System.out.print("("+ i + "," +j+")");
                            //First letter is found.Continue.
                        for(int p=1; p<word.length(); p++){

                        try{
                            for (int S = -1; S <= 1; S++) {
                                for (int SS = -1; SS <= 1; SS++) {
                                    if(S !=0 || SS != 0)
                                        if(matrix[i+S][j+SS].equals(Character.toString(word.charAt(p))) && blocksAvailable[i+S][j+SS] == true || 
                                            matrix[i+S][j+SS].equals(Character.toString(ReversedWord.charAt(p))) && blocksAvailable[i+S][j+SS] == true) {
                                                values[0] = i+S;
                                                values[1] = j+SS;
                                                blocksAvailable[i+S][j+SS] = false;


                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
```

Comment: I'm solving your very problem in my answer above here. Just print the variables xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd in the end of the code. That's the variables corresponding to the indexes of start and end of the word. Please show me the whole code including the matrix.

Comment: @ExceptionalException Actually, your code helped a lot but, I couldn't understand all of it. And here my code, [My Code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y1OW1RYxcchn6tx3ou4qqdjEIB_qjK0JIEou29oJ8pg/edit?usp=sharing).